# column increased by another column by spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

the data source is:

```
   col1
------
    false
    false
    true
    false
    false
    true
    true
    false
```

I add a new column,if value of col1 is true,value col2 increased by 1.
I expect:

```
col1,col2
--

    false,0
    false,0
    true,1
    false,1
    false,1
    true,2
    true,3
    false,3
```

---

how to add this?

Comment: df.withColumn("col2", when($"col1" === true, 1).otherwise(0))

Comment: @pasha701 col2 is not just 1 or 0,it may be 2 or 3 ...,it is like a increamental id

Comment: df.withColumn("col2", when($"col1" === true, $"col2" + lit(1)).otherwise($"col2"))

Comment: @pasha701 `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`col2`' given input columns: [col1];;`  tested with a exception

Comment: Looks like column "col2" which have to be increased does not exists, can be created before incremental code:     df.withColumn("col2",lit(0))

Comment: @pasha701 the result is values of col1 and col2 are the same  .rows of 
 col2 are : `0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0`     `dfa.withColumn("col2",lit(0)).withColumn("col2", when($"col1" === 1, $"col2" + lit(1)).otherwise($"col2")).show()`

Comment: You need to have at least one more column which specifies the order of the bools, otherwise any scripts in Spark for large datasets like these are not going to have deterministic result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Window function can be used:

```
val df = Seq(false, false, true, false, false, true, true, false).toDF("col1")
val ordered = df
  .withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
  .withColumn("increment", when($"col1" === true, 1).otherwise(0))

val idWindow = Window.orderBy("id").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
val result = ordered.select($"col1", sum($"increment").over(idWindow).alias("col2"))
```

Output:

```
+-----+----+
|col1 |col2|
+-----+----+
|false|0   |
|false|0   |
|true |1   |
|false|1   |
|false|1   |
|true |2   |
|true |3   |
|false|3   |
+-----+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
scala> val w = Window.partitionBy(lit(1)).orderBy(lit(1))
scala> val w1 = Window.partitionBy(lit(1)).orderBy("rn")

scala> df.withColumn("tmp", when($"col1" === true, 1).otherwise(0)).withColumn("rn", row_number.over(w)).withColumn("col2", sum("tmp").over(w1)).select("col1","col2").show
+-----+----+
| col1|col2|
+-----+----+
|false|   0|
|false|   0|
| true|   1|
|false|   1|
|false|   1|
| true|   2|
| true|   3|
|false|   3|
+-----+----+
```